# HTACCESS not redirecting on aliased site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a WP multisite hosted on hostgator, it4causeshosting.org, with a subdomain flipm.it4causeshosting.org aliased to flipmusa.org on Godaddy.

If I enter http://flipm.it4causeshosting.org, the htaccess successfully flips it over to https, and I get a lock. This is the code in the hostgator htaccess that I'm assuming makes the change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If I enter https://flipmusa.org, I get a lock icon in the URL address. But, if I enter http instead of https, I get 'not secure.'

I've done similar things on other hosts, with this inserted in htaccess, with no problem, and it successfully switches to https. In this case, richastro.org is aliased to ras2.teebark.com (multisite subdomain).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} richastro\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://richastro.org/$1 [R,L]
```

I've tried hardcoding flipmusa.org in the htaccess file, but I cannot make it switch. I suspect that because the domain is registered with Godaddy, but the servers are on Hostgator it's causing the problem, but I can't figure out why. What can I try to make http://flipmusa.org switch to https?

Comment: Where the domain is registered does not matter, but what server it points to. Unclear which one that it is in this case, but it sounds as if it wasn’t the one where you placed this .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

I finally chatted online with Hostgator, and they cleared out  a bunch of junk in my htaccess having to do with SSL certs (well-known), and set up a very basic htaccess, which did the trick. Lesson learned: if your htaccess is not behaving, take out stuff that you don't understand, or call the vendor. Here's what I endedup with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://flipmusa.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```